# What is wrong with the method that parse the string with the substring calculation?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

All the text i want to extract the text from is from a richTextBox1.Text
First i have a richTextBox1 MouseUp event where i add to a textBox2 and textBox3 string to each textBox and then with the extracting method i want to extract the text between the two strings.

```
bool isFirstClick = false;
List<string> result = new List<string>();

    private void richTextBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isFirstClick == false)
        {
            textBox2.Text = richTextBox1.SelectedText;
            isFirstClick = true;
        }
        else
        {
            textBox3.Text = richTextBox1.SelectedText;
            isFirstClick = false;
            result = ExtractFromString(this.richTextBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text);
        }
    }
```

And the extracting method:

```
private List<string> ExtractFromString(string s, string startTag, string endTag)
        {
            var names = new List<string>();

            int startIndex = 0;
            int endIndex = 0;
            int position = 0;

            startIndex = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(startTag);

            while (startIndex > 0)
            {
                endIndex = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(endTag, position);

                //parsing part
                names.Add(richTextBox1.Text.Substring(startIndex + startTag.Length,
                          endIndex));

                position = endIndex + endTag.Length;

                startIndex = (richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(startTag, position));

                //ending loop
                if (startIndex == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            return names;
        }
```

The problem is that the loop never end. And the List names getting bigger and bigger.

After about 2-3 minutes i'm getting exception on the line:

```
names.Add(richTextBox1.Text.Substring(startIndex + startTag.Length,
                          endIndex));
```

ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string

In this case the startTag is 128 and the endTag is single "
The whole string in this case is: 128.png"
And what it should give in result is .png

The reason i'm using while loop is that i want to find first time in this place .png and then in the next loops in while all the other places in richTextBox1.Text that .png exist.

**Update**

My code now this is the extracting method:

```
private void ExtractFromString(string s, string startTag, string endTag)
{
    int startPos = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(textBox2.Text) + textBox2.Text.Length;
    int endPos = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(textBox3.Text, startPos);
    string extractedText = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(startPos, endPos - startPos).Trim();
}
```

And in textBox2.Text in this example there is the letter: m
In textBox3.Text there is the letters: red
The string in the richTextBox1.Text i wanted to extract from is: murdered
So what I should get as result is: urde

But what I'm getting is:

```
l><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/SearchResultsPage" lang="en-IL"><head><meta content="/images/google_favicon_128.png" itemprop="image"><meta content="origin" id="mref" name="referrer"><title>murde
```

The text in richTextBox1.Text is long, I can't paste it all in here.

**Edit**

This is example of text in the richTextBox1:
[richTextBox1 text content](http://pastebin.com/WAbsqHij)
In the richTextBox what I marked is first tag in textBox2.Text is the letter: x and then in textBox3.Text the end tag was the letters: ns
The word is: xmlns
And the result should be ml
But what i got is: `html11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd\">\n\n<html xml`

In the richTextBox it's line number 8 from the top.
So in some cases it's working but in some cases like this one it doesn't. Maybe it depends on how many chars i mark on each side start and end?

Comment: The reason why you're getting that long string is because you are only looking for a single 'm' as your startTag. String.IndexOf(String) returns the index of the first occurence of the searched string. Could you not just select the text you want to find and count the occurence of that instead of what you're doing now?

Comment: Yes i will make some tests i think it's working, you right there is no need to mark single letter. But another thing is i was mistaken is about the searching after the first extraction all over the text. I said i want to find all places with what i extracted but no. What i need is to find all places that have the same startTag and endTag like i marked and extract from this places the text between the tags. The text can be different.

Comment: I mean in the first places lets say i have the string: hello world and i marked hel adn world so the result will be lo now i want to loop over the text and find more places with startTag hel and endTag world and extrach the text between the tags so in some places it can be as result lo and some places 56 or lolo or anything else. I mean the search should be for the tags and then to extract the text between them in all places and add the extracted strings to a List.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if I understand you correctly. The user makes two selections in a text and you want to extract the text that lies between these two selections?

My question to you is then: Why do you want to return a list and not just a string containing the text?

This is how I would do what I think that you actually want to do:

```
int startPos = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(textBox2.Text) + textBox2.Text.Length;
int endPos = richTextBox2.Text.IndexOf(textBox3.Text, startPos);
string extractedText = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(startPos, endPos - startPos).Trim();
```

I recommend that you only do this once to get the substring that you want to count the occurence of within your text. Then have a look at this link in order to count the number of times your substring occurs in the text. 
http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Count_occurrences_of_a_substring#C.23

Comment: You understood right. But in your solution i'm getting exception on: string extractedText = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(startPos, endPos - startPos).Trim(); Length cannot be less than zero. When textBox2.Text is 128 and textBox3.Text is " and the text between them to extract is .png

Comment: And the richTextBox2 should be also richTextBox1 i have only one richTextBox. And last thing it should be in loop i think thats why i used a List since i want to find all the places in richTextBox1.Text that the extracted text .png exist. It can be only at one place or maybe in other 30 places in the text.

Comment: Ah, yes, that is indeed a possibility, if you change endPos to count from startPos you won't encounter that issue. There is however no guarantee that you will get the correct index when the searched string is just a single quotation mark.

Comment: I mean that i'm extracting for example the string .png in the specific indexs for example start index 34 end index 40 now i have a string .png now i want to search for .png all over the richTextBox1.Text and if it's exist in more places extract this places too. So in the end in the List<string> i can have one item or maybe 30 items.

Comment: Alright, but why would you want a list containing a number of strings all equal to ".png"? Would it not suffice to just count the number of times the string occurs within your text?

Comment: You right so i will limit later that for searching you will have to mark in both starttag and endtag more then one char.

Comment: You right maybe instead adding to the List many times .png maybe to add the indexs start and end for each place. For example the first item will be something like: start: 23 end: 40 then second item start: 50 end: 60 but i would like also to be able to add as an option to the List all the .png's i found.

Comment: I tried now your edited solution and it worked for 3 times i tried in a row but then on the 4 time textBox2.Text was m and textBox3.Text was red and the text between is  urder but instead getting urde i got a very long string. Maybe i need to reset the variables somewhere each time ?

Comment: Can you update your question so that we can see what your code looks like now? And maybe the value of richTextBox1.Text as well?

Comment: I edited the question twice last time now i also added a link for the text i'm using in the richTextBox.